# How To Implement Full Search in Case Type using Salesforce?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, salesforce-lightning

I need to build out a solution to create a search field on the new Case Type Data object in all 3 of the Level fields and populate based on selection.

Similar to SF Global Search I  would like to type 2-3 characters in the text search field and it would find the matching text in the Level1-3 fields and when selected the Level 1-3 field would populate.

[image]

This is the apex class

```
                 public class PickListHandler {
                @AuraEnabled
                public static List<String> getLevel1(){
                List<String> tempLst1 = new List<String>();
                    for(AggregateResult  ar : [select Level_1__c,COUNT(id) from Case_Type_Data__c  group by Level_1__c])
                {
                    tempLst1.add(''+ar.get('Level_1__c'));
                }

                return tempLst1;
                  
                  
                } 
                
                @AuraEnabled
                public static List<String> getLevel2(string strName){
                List<String> tempLst2 = new List<String>();
                   for(AggregateResult  ar : [select Level_2__c,COUNT(id) from Case_Type_Data__c where Level_1__c=:strName  group by Level_2__c])
                {
                   tempLst2.add(''+ar.get('Level_2__c'));
                }

                return tempLst2;
                  
                } 
                
                @AuraEnabled
                public static List<String> getLevel3(string strName1,string strName2){
                 List<String> tempLst3 = new List<String>();
                  for(AggregateResult  ar : [select Level_3__c,COUNT(id) from Case_Type_Data__c  where Level_1__c=:strName1 and Level_2__c=:strName2 group by Level_3__c])
                {
                   tempLst3.add(''+ar.get('Level_3__c'));
                }

                return tempLst3;
                  
                  
                } 
                     
                 @AuraEnabled
                 public  static String  savecasetype(string level1,string level2,string level3,string id){
                 string strMsg='successfull';
                      try{
                 ERT_Case_Type__c obj=new ERT_Case_Type__c();
                 Obj.Case__c = id;
                 System.debug('CASE  = '+ Obj.Case__c); 
                 Obj.Level_1__c=level1;
                 System.debug('Level1  = '+ Obj.Level_1__c); 
                 Obj.Level_2__c=level2;
                 System.debug('Level2  = '+ Obj.Level_2__c); 
                 Obj.Level_3__c=level3;
                 System.debug('Level3  = '+ Obj.Level_3__c); 
                 Insert obj;
              
                 }
                 
                catch(Exception ex){
                        strMsg='error';
                    }
                 return strMsg;  
            }
                
                 
                
                

            }
```

This is the Picklist handler component

```
                <aura:component controller="PickListHandler" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
                    <!-- Actions-->
                    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
                    <!-- variable-->
                    <aura:attribute name="lstLevel1" type="String[]" />
                     <aura:attribute name="lstLevel2" type="String[]" />
                      <aura:attribute name="lstL3" type="String[]" />
                    <span> Level 1</span>
                    <ui:inputSelect aura:id="ddLevel1" change="{!c.getLvl1}">
                        <ui:inputSelectOption label="-Select-" value="true"/>        
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.lstLevel1}" var="value">          
                            <ui:inputSelectOption label="{!value}" text="{!value}" />
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </ui:inputSelect>
                    <span>Level 2</span>
                    <ui:inputSelect aura:id="ddLevel2" change="{!c.getSelectedValue}">
                        <ui:inputSelectOption label="-Select-" value="true"/>        
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.lstLevel2}" var="value">          
                            <ui:inputSelectOption label="{!value}" text="{!value}" />
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </ui:inputSelect>
                     <span>Level 3</span>
                    <ui:inputSelect aura:id="ddLevel3" >
                        <ui:inputSelectOption label="-Select-" value="true"/>        
                        <aura:iteration items="{!v.lstL3}" var="value">          
                            <ui:inputSelectOption label="{!value}" text="{!value}" />
                        </aura:iteration>
                    </ui:inputSelect>
                   <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Save" onclick="{!c.onConfirm}" />
                </aura:component>
```

Regards,
Carolyn

Comment: What does this screenshot show? Some standard quick action that saves custom record? Aura component? Lightning Web Component (LWC)? Can you post some code because syntax in both will be bit different? Do you have Visual Studio or similar thing and ever done LWC development? Worst case - visualforce?

Comment: @eyescream  thank you for reply here is the updated code ,if you can suggest where and what change is needed  to make this search functionality working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're asking for a lot, we wouldn't have your custom object. And this is old code, [`ui:inputSelect` is deprecated for 1 year now](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_aura_ui_deprecate.htm). I'll try to help a bit but the whole thing needs your work too. And examples we can reproduce easily.

I'm going to cheat and use Philippe Ozil's [ready component for the lookup/autocomplete thing](https://github.com/pozil/sfdc-ui-lookup).
It means you'd have to save [`LookupSearchResult`](https://github.com/pozil/sfdc-ui-lookup/blob/master/src/main/default/classes/LookupSearchResult.cls) class, the [whole aura component](https://github.com/pozil/sfdc-ui-lookup/tree/master/src/main/default/aura/Lookup) and [2 aura events](https://github.com/pozil/sfdc-ui-lookup/tree/master/src/main/default/aura) in your org before reading below. That's some prep work but it's battle-tested :)

[image]

**Apex class**

```java
public with sharing class Stack64129038 {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<LookupSearchResult> search(String searchTerm, List<String> selectedIds){
        if(String.isBlank(searchTerm) || searchTerm.length() < 2){
            return null;
        }
        String t = '%' + searchTerm + '%'; // decide how you want to search, "starts with", "includes" or what
        
        List<Case_Type_Data__c> records = [SELECT Id, Name, Level_1__c, Level_2__c, Level_3__c
            FROM Case_Type_Data__c
            WHERE Level_1__c LIKE :t OR Level_2__c LIKE :t OR Level_3__c LIKE :t
            ORDER BY Level_1__c, Level_2__c, Level_3__c
            LIMIT 20];
        
        /* You could also experiment with SOSL?
        records =  [FIND :('*' + searchTerm + '*') IN ALL FIELDS 
            RETURNING Case_Type_Data__c(Id, Name, Level_1__c, Level_2__c, Level_3__c)][0];
        */
        
        List<LookupSearchResult> results = new List<LookupSearchResult>();
        for(Case_Type_Data__c ctd : records){
            results.add(new LookupSearchResult(ctd.Id, 'Case_Type_Data__c', 'standard:case_wrap_up', ctd.Name,
                String.join(new List<String>{ctd.Level_1__c , ctd.Level_2__c, ctd.Level_3__c}, '; ')
            ));
        }
        return results;
    } 
}
```

**Aura component** (html part)

```html
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" controller="Stack64129038">
    <aura:attribute access="private" type="List" name="selection" default="[]"/>
    <aura:attribute access="private" type="List" name="errors" default="[]"/>

    <lightning:card title="New Case Type">
        
        <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="myForm" objectApiName="ERT_Case_Type__c" onsubmit="{!c.onSubmit}" onsuccess="{!c.onSuccess}">
        <lightning:messages />
        <c:Lookup selection="{!v.selection}" onSearch="{!c.lookupSearch}" onSelection="{!c.useSelected}" errors="{!v.errors}" label="Search" placeholder="Search Case Types Data"/>
        <lightning:inputField aura:id="Level_1__c" fieldName="Level_1__c" />
        <lightning:inputField aura:id="Level_2__c" fieldName="Level_2__c" />
        <lightning:inputField aura:id="Level_3__c" fieldName="Level_3__c" />
        <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" type="submit" name="save" label="Save" />
    </lightning:recordEditForm>
    </lightning:card>
</aura:component>
```

**Aura component** - JS controller part

```js
({
    lookupSearch : function(component, event, helper) {
        // Get the lookup component that fired the search event
        const lookupComponent = event.getSource();
        const serverSearchAction = component.get('c.search');
        lookupComponent.search(serverSearchAction);
    },

    useSelected: function(component, event, helper) {
        const selection = component.get('v.selection');
        const errors = component.get('v.errors');
        
        if (selection.length) {
            if(errors.length){  // Clear errors, if any
                component.set('v.errors', []);
            }
            let levels = selection[0].subtitle.split('; ');
            component.find('Level_1__c').set('v.value', levels[0]);
            component.find('Level_2__c').set('v.value', levels[1]);
            component.find('Level_3__c').set('v.value', levels[2]);
        }
    },
    onSubmit: function(component, event, helper) {
        debugger;
        event.preventDefault();       // stop the form from submitting
        var fields = event.getParam('fields');
        fields.Case__c = component.get('v.recordId'); // link to "this" Case
        component.find('myForm').submit(fields);
    },
    onSuccess: function(component, event, helper){
        var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
        toastEvent.setParams({
            "title": "Success!",
            "message": "Case Type saved OK, refreshing",
            "type": "success"
        });
        toastEvent.fire();
        $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire(); // reload page
    }
})
```