# Custom Salesforce Lightning App giving "You dont have access to this record"

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

Custom Lightning App named "Stack" giving "You dont have access to this record Contact "
Trying to follow steps in  [How To Implement Full Search in Case Type using Salesforce?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64129038/how-to-implement-full-search-in-case-type-using-salesforce/64172475#64172475)

[image]

Here is Org wide defaults of the custom object ERT Case Type data
[image]

Here is **Apex** code of stack.aspx

```
                public class Stack {
                      @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
                    public static List<LookupSearchResult> search(String searchTerm, List<String> selectedIds){
                        if(String.isBlank(searchTerm) || searchTerm.length() < 2){
                            return null;
                        }
                        String t = '%' + searchTerm + '%'; // decide how you want to search, "starts with", "includes" or what
                        
                        List<ERT_Case_Type_Data__c> records = [SELECT Id, Name, Level_1__c, Level_2__c, Level_3__c
                            FROM ERT_Case_Type_Data__c
                            WHERE Level_1__c LIKE :t OR Level_2__c LIKE :t OR Level_3__c LIKE :t
                            ORDER BY Level_1__c, Level_2__c, Level_3__c
                            LIMIT 20];
                        
                        /* You could also experiment with SOSL?
                        records =  [FIND :('*' + searchTerm + '*') IN ALL FIELDS 
                            RETURNING Case_Type_Data__c(Id, Name, Level_1__c, Level_2__c, Level_3__c)][0];
                        */
                        
                        List<LookupSearchResult> results = new List<LookupSearchResult>();
                        for(ERT_Case_Type_Data__c ctd : records){
                            results.add(new LookupSearchResult(ctd.Id, 'ERT_Case_Type_Data__c', 'standard:case_wrap_up', ctd.Name,
                                String.join(new List<String>{ctd.Level_1__c , ctd.Level_2__c, ctd.Level_3__c}, '; ')
                            ));
                        }
                        return results;
                    } 

                }
```

Here is **Aura component**(html part)

```
                <aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" controller="Stack">
                    <aura:attribute access="global" type="List" name="selection" default="[]"/>
                    <aura:attribute access="global" type="List" name="errors" default="[]"/>

                    <lightning:card title="New Case Type">
                        
                        <lightning:recordEditForm aura:id="myForm" objectApiName="ERT_Case_Type__c" onsubmit="{!c.onSubmit}" onsuccess="{!c.onSuccess}">
                        <lightning:messages />
                        <c:Lookup selection="{!v.selection}" onSearch="{!c.lookupSearch}" onSelection="{!c.useSelected}" errors="{!v.errors}" label="Search" placeholder="Search Case Types Data"/>
                        <lightning:inputField aura:id="Level_1__c" fieldName="Level_1__c" />
                        <lightning:inputField aura:id="Level_2__c" fieldName="Level_2__c" />
                        <lightning:inputField aura:id="Level_3__c" fieldName="Level_3__c" />
                        <lightning:button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" type="submit" name="save" label="Save" />
                    </lightning:recordEditForm>
                    </lightning:card>
                </aura:component>
```

Here is **Aura component - JS controller part**

```
({
    lookupSearch : function(component, event, helper) {
    // Get the lookup component that fired the search event
    const lookupComponent = event.getSource();
    const serverSearchAction = component.get('c.search');
    lookupComponent.search(serverSearchAction);
},

useSelected: function(component, event, helper) {
    const selection = component.get('v.selection');
    const errors = component.get('v.errors');
    
    if (selection.length) {
        if(errors.length){  // Clear errors, if any
            component.set('v.errors', []);
        }
        let levels = selection[0].subtitle.split('; ');
        component.find('Level_1__c').set('v.value', levels[0]);
        component.find('Level_2__c').set('v.value', levels[1]);
        component.find('Level_3__c').set('v.value', levels[2]);
    }
},
onSubmit: function(component, event, helper) {
    debugger;
    event.preventDefault();       // stop the form from submitting
    var fields = event.getParam('fields');
    fields.Case__c = component.get('v.recordId'); // link to "this" Case
    component.find('myForm').submit(fields);
},
onSuccess: function(component, event, helper){
    var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
    toastEvent.setParams({
        "title": "Success!",
        "message": "Case Type saved OK, refreshing",
        "type": "success"
    });
    toastEvent.fire();
    $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire(); // reload page
   }
})
```

Please help me in removing this access error

Regards,
Carolyn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it's sharing related (so not the org-wide settings). If it was sharing it'd simply always return 0 results but no big red errors.

If you remove the line with `<c:Lookup selection="{!v.selection}" onSearch="{!c.lookupSearch}" onSelection="{!c.useSelected}" errors="{!v.errors}" label="Search" placeholder="Search Case Types Data"/>` does the error go away? If it stays - it's problem with permissions around the custom code or `Case_Type_Data__c`). If it goes away - it's something with creating `ERT_Case_Type__c`)

Check the Profile (or Permission Sets if you use them) rights to:

- Read the source object (`Case_Type_Data__c`) and all referenced fields (`Level_1__c`...)
- Create the target object (`ERT_Case_Type__c`) and read/edit all referenced fields (`Level1__c`... but also `Case__c`)
- Read on the `Case` object and `Case.CaseNumber`, `Case.Subject` fields
- Permission to execute the Apex class (renamed to `Stack`, right?). And maybe add permission to run `LookupSearchResult` too.

I suspect you have enabled some critical updates (Setup -> Critical updates or Setup -> Release Updates) like "Restrict Access to @AuraEnabled Apex Methods for Authenticated Users Based on User Profile" or "Require Permission to View Record Names in Lookup Fields"

Comment: if you can answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64235294/auto-reset-the-custom-salesforce-lightning-level-fields

Comment: basically auto reset level1,2 and 3 fields to null after clearing text in search